# Excel VBA - ADO Connection to Azure Data Lake Store Issue

Tags: excel, ms-access, azure-storage, vba

I am having some issues trying to run a very simple VBA script in Excel VBA using ADO to connect to an Access database file (.accdb) located on my company's Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) site. We are using Excel 2016 and Access 2016.

I have no problem pulling the data into Excel from this Access database file located on ADLS through Power Query by going to `Data -> Get Data -> From Azure -> From Azure Data Lake Store` and connecting directly to the file from within Excel. Thus, it seems like this is not a security or account access issue.

Here is the VBA code that I have been trying to tweak in order to make a successful connection from Excel to the Access database file located on ADLS:

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
StrProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password=my_ADLS_password;User ID=my_ADLS_account;"
StrSource = "Data Source=my_access_DB_file_path_on_ADLS;"
cn.Open StrProvider & StrSource
```

For security reasons, I cannot provide my ADLS account information in the code above.

I really just need help in determining the appropriate VBA ADO code syntax to make this connection work. I have spent a lot of time researching online about this specific issue with no luck.

I do NOT want to simply automate the creation of a Power Query using VBA to pull data into Excel from the source. I know this is an option but it doesn't suit my needs. I want to use ADO to establish this connection on the fly and hopefully, have the potential to read/write data from/to the database using SQL. In other words, I plan on not only being able to run SELECT SQL statements on the data source, but also INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while retrieving the data using the Data Menu? this may show a different and maybe better/easier way to do it.

Comment: Ricardo - No, I had not tried that. I just recorded the macro and the code appears to be using a different Provider =  "Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1". However, I have tried this same provider in my VBA code previously and it did not work.

Comment: Not sure if there are other problems, but you are missing `OLEDB;` in front of your connection string. Which to the best of my knowledge, is required for OLEDBs

Comment: I believe you are going to have to mount the Azure File Storage as a network drive, then give the path to that drive. I'm guessing Power Query has built in logic to allow it to connect outside of the filesystem, which you don't have when using connection strings and ADODB. Obviously that's kind of a crummy solution if you are going to distribute this file to other since they will have to mount at the same drive letter. Perhaps you could write some VBA to perform that mount... yuck tho :/

Comment: JNevill - I do plan on distributing this file to multiple users, globally. Your idea of automatically mapping the Azure File Storage as a network drive on the user's end through VBA might actually work. I would only have to do it one time, when the user first opens the Excel file, so that the queries will actually run while they are using the file. I also might be able to use my company's cloud-based Microsoft Sharepoint site to house the Access file as an alternative, but I am assuming that I would still have to resort to mapping THAT drive on the user's end as well. Thanks for your input!

Comment: It would be nice if I could just do a straight connection to the Access DB file on ADLS via ADO. It seems like the connection string would be structured in a similar way to connecting to say, Google Drive, but I am not sure. ADLS is basically a server that requires a UID and PW to connect to which would obviously have to be in the ADO connection string somehow.  You would also need the right provider to connect to an Access DB, which I am assuming is just Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. Has anyone tried connecting Excel ADO to an Access DB file on Google Drive?